# How to have Sublime Text 2 show git folders and files in the sidebar?

Tags: windows, git, sublime-text-2

When adding a folder to a Sublime Text 2 project, it doesn't seem to show `.git` subfolders. It also seems these files cannot be opened by <kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd>.

I disabled the Git plugin but that didn't help.

Comment: I can't reproduce. I opened a project directory, then did mkdir .t in the dos-prompt creating a folder, and it showed immediately in the project. In that folder i created t.txt and used Ctrl+P to open it.   I'm running build 2181.

Comment: are you running on windows? I don't know if . make files hidden on windows...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Sublime Text, go to Preferences -> Settings - Default, scroll down to line 290 and remove .git from 'folder_exclude_patterns' property

Comment: or better, override it in your user settings!

Comment: The line number will change. Do a search for 'folder_exclude_patterns' instead.

Comment: User settings is probably the right answer but, since you probably want to start with what they have and copy that into your config to be modified rather than making your own list from scratch, I'll mention that as of 2.0.2 folder_exclude_patterns is down to line 327.

Comment: Though, now that I look at it, I'm setting mine to [] because it's only scm dirs and I may want to modify items in those dirs for any of them.

Answer (score 4):

Go to `Preferences -> Settings-User`. Modify the rule `folder_exclude_patterns` to contain an array of patterns to exclude. I chose to leave it empty:

```
{
    "bold_folder_labels": true,
    "caret_style": "phase",
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Solarized (Dark).tmTheme",
    "font_size": 14,
    "highlight_line": true,
    "line_padding_bottom": 1,
    "line_padding_top": 1,
    "tab_size": 4,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
    "folder_exclude_patterns" : [] // the rule in question
}
```

Comment: "Settings - Default" in my case, but good answer, thanks!